# Symfony3 persist embedded form in Doctrine2 (Integrity constraint violation: null field)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities Game and GameSource. Game have only one GameSource.

Game.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="game")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GameRepository")
*/
class Game
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="tinyint",options={"unsigned" = true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GameSource",mappedBy="game",cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\GameSource")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $gameSource;
}
```

GameSource.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="game_source")
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GameSourceRepository")
 */
class GameSource
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",options={"unsigned" = true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Game",inversedBy="gameSource")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $game;
}
```

Form GameType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Game;
use AppBundle\Form\GameSourceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\{
    AbstractType,
    FormBuilderInterface
};
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\{
    TextType,
    CheckboxType
};

class GameType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label'    => 'Nazwa rozgrywki',
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('gameSource', GameSourceType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Game::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

And GameController.php - addAction

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $gameEntity = new Game();

    $form = $this->createForm(GameType::class, $gameEntity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($gameEntity);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

When i tried persist record i have error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'game_id' cannot be null
```

The problem is that:
Entity GameSource does not see id of Game when i try save him. Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your GameSourceType class?

Comment: I cant edit my question yet. I create link with this class [link](http://wklejto.pl/567166)

Comment: Show me your setGame() and setGameSource() functions

Comment: SetGame and setGameSource [link](http://wklejto.pl/567190)

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your entities, when you call your `setGameSource()` function, you will want to tie the Game entity to the GameSource.  For example, instead of:

```
public function setGameSource(?GameSource $gameSource): self
{
    $this->gameSource = $gameSource;

    return $this;
}
```

you will want to instead do this:

```
public function setGameSource(?GameSource $gameSource): self
{
    $this->gameSource = $gameSource;
    $this->gameSource->setGame($this);

    return $this;
}
```

That way the entities will be properly connected.

Comment: This it is!! Thx your so much for this solution.